# Determining size of PCollection

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am writing a dataflow job which will read data from GCS and BigQuery.
This job will consolidate the data read from two sources. Consolidated data is just String.

Then this job will publish the consolidated data into external api.Custom sink is written to publish the consolidated data.

External API will not allow to publish data if the consolidated data is more than 1 GB.

I just want to fail the dataflow job if the consolidated data is more than 1 GB. How can I get the size of data present in PCollection?

Currently I am determining the size using the below code

```
    private static class CalculateSize extends PTransform<PCollection<String>, PCollection<Long>> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7383871712471335638L;

    @Override
    public PCollection<Long> apply(PCollection<String> input) {
        return input
            .apply(ParDo.named("IndividualSize").of(new DoFn<String, Long>() {

                @Override
                public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
                    c.output(Integer.valueOf(c.element().length()).longValue());
                }
            }))
            .apply(Combine.globally(new Sum.SumLongFn()));
    }

}
```

Is there any other better way to find the size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is the correct way to do this. Determining approximately how much your data will take up when written to your sink in its expected format is entirely sink-specific and Dataflow cannot do this for you. So, writing a function to manually compute this is the best way to do it.

Note that you need to account for different sources of overhead. E.g. if your sink was, say, a CSV file, then simply adding up lengths of individual record fields would give you an under-estimate of the number of bytes the file would take up. You would need to account for the commas, spaces, newlines, quotes, multi-byte characters etc. This overhead is also entirely format-specific.

But if it is only important to make sure you don't exceed 1GB, you can simply slightly pessimistically scale up your approximation.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I just to make sure it is not more than 1 GB. I don't want the exact size. So I think having a pessimistic value will do for me considering the extra characters, multi-byte characters etc.